# How two create a login page for two different kind of user roles in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I am making a website for my fraternity using wordpress (This is my first time using wordpress) and I am creating a login page for actives and alumni to use. Once they login depending on their role, They see either active stuff or alumni stuff. I got it to work just as a basic login page but the client wants me to create a login page for active brothers and one for alumni. I am curious how to make this work because it seems rather difficult and I have been on this issue for the past couple days. So I

I have tried many plugins and I probably used the right one and just didn't use it correctly. If anyone has done this before in the past and could help a newbie out that would be great!

Comment: please include more information about what you have tried, what you expected and what happened.

Comment: I tried using the wp membership login plugin where I created the two types of membership and I expected it to be able to log the user in and them see the content for that membership but that did not work. It didn't log them in. Then I tried using the user role editor plugin expecting me to be able to do the same thing but that just logged them in to the wp backend

Answer (score 0):

Until the user logs in, you will not be able to find out what his role is!

Regarding the login form - you can create two separate pages(possibly with different designs) with different urls, for example `/login/brothers/` and `/login/alumni/`. But the purpose of the pages will be one - authorization. And after authorization, redirect the user according to his role.